# How to use Google's AutoValue with Android Studio's Unit Testing support?

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, auto-value

I want to use AutoValue with Android Studios' new Unit Testing support.

Is this possible? Or can generated code not be seen by `src/test/java` classes?

The `android-apt` plugin does not work with `testApt` scope

Comment: There should be no problem with this, are you running into specific issues?  The code is compiled before tests are run so it should have the same access.